# Reset xrandr dpi to default

Tags: xrandr, dpi, hdpi

I changed my dpi with the following command:

`$ xrandr --dpi 144`

How can I reset it to the default value? Or how can I know what the default value is so I can rerun the same command but with that different argument?

Comment: After `xrandr --dpi 144` I always use `xrandr --dpi 96`. Can't remember if that is the default or not though...